# Hypothesis testing of multiple genes for multiple samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If I have an x number of genes for n number of samples with values representing gene expression values for cancer. And I have the same data for a healthy individual and I want to check if the change is significant! How do I put it in hypothesis terms?
Also, what’s a fold change? And can it be of use in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You have a healthy person and a person with cancer. You have n samples from each person, and each sample has x genes.

You need to judge if my following makes sense or not, because I am not a domain expert.

1. assume there is a correct configuation/value/sequence for each of the x gene, then for each of the x gene, I check if it is correct, and count the number of wrong gene, so the count is in the range from 0 to x. 0: nothing wrong; x: all wrong.
2. then I have n counts for healthy person and n counts for the unhealthy person.
3. my hypothesis $H_0$ is distribution of counts of the unhealthy person is the same as that of the healthy person